# Galaxy Mini Emulator LCD Density

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to emulate the Samsung Galaxy Mini. I´ve set the resolution to 240x320 and the LCD density to 180. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Its absolutely correct....

Answer (score 0):

According to this site: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_mini_s5570-3725.php

The density is 127